# File(String name) - Creates also a new file if already a "name"-named file exists?

Tags: java, file

If i write

```
File file = new File("file.txt");
```

and in my actually project direcotry exists already a "file.txt" file, will my acutally file.txt file used or will it be overwritten with a new created file.txt by

```
File file = new File("file.txt");
```

?

Background is, that i want read in a existing file.

Comment: Why don't you try it? And read the javadoc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new File("file.txt")` doesn't create a file at all. It just creates a `File` object related to the path you give it. From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html):

> `public class File`
>
> `extends Object`
>
> `implements Serializable, Comparable<File>`
>
> An **abstract** representation of file and directory **pathnames**.

*(My emphasis.)*

If you want to read the file, you might use [`File#exists`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29) or [`File#canRead`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canRead%28%29) to see if it exists and is readable, and to actually read the file you might pass a `File` instance into the constructor for a [`FileReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) (character data) or [`FileInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) (raw data). If you call those constructors to read a file you can't read, you'll get an `IOException` or one of its subclasses (for instance, `FileNotFoundException` if the file wasn't found).

Example:

```
FileReader reader = null;
File file = new File("file.txt");
if (file.canRead()) {
    try {
        // Open the file
        reader = new FileReader(file);

        // ...read the file...

        // Close it
        reader.close();
        reader = null;
    }
    finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            // An exception occurred, close the reader but don't throw a new exception
            try {
                reader.close();
            }
            catch (Exception) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In Java 7 and later, using the new [`try-with-resources` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3):

```
File file = new File("file.txt");
if (file.canRead()) {
    try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(file)) {
        // Open the file
        reader = new FileReader(file);

        // ...read the file...
    }
}
```

The Java 7 `try-with-resources` statement handles the mess around making sure the reader is closed for us.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, misunderstood the question. Just creating a File object will not create any new file. If the file already exists reading will not be a problem, if it is not found it throws FileNotFoundException.

Answer (score 0):

If file exists, it will use that existing file. But, of course, purpouse of it depends on file stream (input/output) you will be working with.